# VueJS Nested Builder Example

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to VueJS and am trying to make a small page builder application where you can create sections and add subsections to each of those. I'm not sure how to setup the Vue data property to allow this. Any insight on how you would go about doing something like this would be appreciated. Here's my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="app">
        <form>
            <input type="text" v-model="title"> {{title}}<br>
            <button type="button" v-on:click="addSection()">Add Section</button>
        </form>

        <h1>Sections</h1>
        <div v-for="(section, index) in sections">
            <h2>{{section.title}}</h2>
            <form>
                <input type="text" v-model="subTitle"> {{subTitle}}<br>
                <button type="button" v-on:click="addSubSection()">Add SubSection</button>
            </form>

            <div v-for="(subsection, index) in subsections">
                <h3>{{subsection.subTitle</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                title: '',
                sections: []
            },
            methods: {
                addSection: function(e) {
                    this.sections.push({title: this.title});
                    this.title = '';
                },
                addSubSection: function(sectionIndex) {
                    this.sections[sectionIndex].push({subTitle: this.subTitle});
                    this.subTitle = '';
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your `sections` is an object, not an array so `this.sections[sectionIndex].push()` won't work. You should probably add a `sections` property to each new section, eg

```js
this.sections.push({ title: this.title, sections: [] })
```

and when adding a sub-section

```js
this.sections[sectionIndex].sections.push({ subTitle: this.subTitle })
```

---

You should also have a data property for `subTitle`